# UnsatisfiedLinkError - Unable to load library - Native library not found in resource path

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, java-native-interface, jna

I have the following error at runtime, while trying to run Tess4J:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libtesseract302': Native library (win32-x86-64/libtesseract302.dll) not found in resource path ([myproject/target/classes/, ...some jars...])
```

My questions are:

1) What exactly it tries to find and where?

2) Why is it apparently searches for `myproject/target/classes/` directory? I set it nowhere.

3) Why is it ignores "native directory path" I set for `tess4j.jar` in user library descripto in Eclipse? My DLLs are there. If it didn't ignore the path, it would find DLLs.

4) Why is it apparently prepending DLL name with `win32-x86-64/`? I set this nowhere. Is this standard prefix of some API?

5) What is "resource path"? How to set it?

Comment: did you ever find a good answer?

Answer (score 6):

Like the error says, it's looking for `win32-x86-64/libtesseract302.dll` in `java.class.path`.  Part of your classpath apparently includes `myproject/target/classes`.

The prefix represents the platform and architecture of the shared library to be loaded, which allows shared libraries for different targets to be included in the same archive.  If JNA cannot find the requested library name in the system load path, then it attempts to find it within your resource path (extracting it, if necessary).  So if you put the DLL in a jar file, you'll need to give it the `win32-x86-64` prefix in order for it to load.

The "resource path" is nominally your class path; basically anywhere reachable by `ClassLoader.getResource()`.

Answer (score 5):

The error stems from your trying to load 32-bit DLLs in 64-bit JVM. The possible solution is switch to 32-bit JVM; alternatively, use [64-bit Tesseract and Leptonica DLLs](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/tree/master/src/lib/TesseractOcr/x64).

Comment: No. That would only produce the same error, if it could not find the DLL either. You get what I mean?

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue, sorted with the following lines

```
System.load("/usr/local/lib/liblept.so.5")
System.loadLibrary("tesseract")
```

For your case, it might be different libraries but in the end is pretty much the same: just load the libraries that you need manually.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use JNA API `http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjna351jar.htm` to load native library? Once you putted into your project classpath, you add this code

`NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("libtesseract302", "your native lib path");` make sure you have this libtesseract302.dll file, normally it is located at `windows32` folder.

For example, if your libtesseract302.dll file in somewhere `c:/abcv/aaa/libtesseract302.dll` then you just set the path like this `NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("libtesseract302", "c:/abcv/aaa");`

I don't know how windows path look like either `c:/abcv/aaa` or `c:\\abcv\\aaa\\`

if you want easier way, just put all your necessary dll file into your windows32 folder, JVM will take care of it.

Another issue might be you were not installing the application correctly or the application version is unmatch with your jar version. try to install the latest application and download the latest jar to try again. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found that this "resource path" is not set by "native directory path" .
You can however add new folders to it by using "Add External Class Folder" in the Library tab, even if this folder does not contain any class file but native library files(like DLL on Windows)

Answer (score 1):

A few days ago I ran into the same error message when trying to load a C++ DLL with JNA. It turned out that the cause was a missing DLL that my DLL depended on.

In my case it was the MS Visual Studio 2012 redistributable, which I then downloaded and installed on the machine and the problem was gone. Try using **Dependency Walker** to find any missing libraries and install them.

Answer (score 1):

I think an easier way to get around this error would be to revert to an earlier version where you were not getting this error. Right click on the project folder and navigate to local history to revert to an earlier version. I verified this workaround on the android studio installed on Mac OS Big sur.